# How to use Angular mat-chip-row?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, components, mat-chip

I had import MatChips Module in both the app component and my class component, but it still shows this error:

```
NG 8001: 'mat-chip-row' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-chip-row' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-chip-row' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SHCEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

62 <mat-chip-row *ngFor=let key of courseLookup" (removed)="removeFormat(key)">
```

I tried to npm install because I thought it was problem causes by module not install in my project but still didn't work. And they had been both import in app module and class component. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Only works in Material version 15 or higher, please check your version